# How to get X11 GUI from AWS EC2 instances through Proxy server

Tags: amazon-ec2, x11

We have wired situation, we have one aws EC2 Redhat7 instance. We connect to that instance  with a http proxy and authentication. Now we have to get GUI from the instance to install some GUI based applications. We have installed x11 packages, and enabled x11 forwarding in /etc/ssh/sshd-config and tried exporting display to our local Desktop IPs but no luck. Please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance,
San..

Answer (score 0):

X11 protocol isn't proxyable, at least through HTTP-proxy. So it the SSH. So you either need a X11-aware proxy (which existance  I am not aware of, for example) or you need to set up a VPN.